# How can I merge two sequences in clojure?

Tags: clojure, sequences

What is an idiomatic way to merge (or retrieve the union of) two lists (or sequences) in Clojure?

```
(merge l1 l2)
```

doesn't seem to be the solution:

```
a=> (merge '(1 2 3) '(2 3 4))
((2 3 4) 1 2 3)
```

Comment: how do you define "merge"? e.g. do duplicates exist, and if so how are duplicates handled? also do you know if the lists are already sorted?

Comment: FYI. The function name, `merge`, has already been taken by `clojure.core`. To avoid confusion, you may choose another name for your `merge` function. See http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/merge

Comment: The poster was in fact using clojure.core/merge, but not on hash-maps or otherwise associative data, and said function has undefined behavior in that context.

Answer (score 30):

I think andih's solution works great. Here is an alternate way because hey why not. It uses [`concat`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/concat) and  [`distinct`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/distinct):

```
user> (distinct (concat '(1 2 3) '(2 3 4)))
=> (1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: I would just advise against concat for performance reasons, as it is surprisingly slow. See my answer below for further discussion.

Comment: @rplevy thanks for the comment (and your answer below). I had not realized that concat has performance problem.

Answer (score 18):

If what you want is actually distinct unsorted data (sets), you should be using Clojure's set data structure instead of vectors or lists. And as andih suggested indirectly, there is a core library for set operations: http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.set-api.html

```
(require '[clojure.set :refer [union]])

(union #{1 2 3} #{3 4 5})
=> #{1 2 3 4 5}
```

If sets are for whatever reason not what you want, then read on. Careful with `concat` when you have a significant amount of data in your sequences, and consider using `into` which is much better optimized as a vector merging algorithm. I don't know why concat is not implemented using into (or better yet-- why does concat even exist? BTW while into is significantly faster than concat, it is still way way slower than conj. Bagwell's RRB trees, compatible with both Clojure and Scala, will solve this problem, but are not yet implemented for Clojure).

To rephrase Omri's non-set solution in terms of 'into':

```
(distinct (into [1 2 3] [3 4 5]))
=> (1 2 3 4 5)
```

Comment: what's so bad about concat? It's constant-time because it's lazy, not the linear-time implementation you get in strict languages.

Comment: also, how can into be slower than conj? it's implemented using conj. `(into foo bar)` is the same as `(reduce conj foo bar)`, except that it will use transients if they are available.

Comment: No, I said conj is faster! (but if you need to concatenate vectors and not merely conj one onto the other, these are different needs to have.)

Comment: Philip: into uses transients, very similar to the transients for vector concatenation example in Joy of Clojure in fact, which is a good place to look for more discussion on this.

Comment: @PhilipPotter surely `concat` cannot be constant time for all inputs? Has to be linear time as size of input lenghts grow?

Comment: @pete sorry for late reply.  `concat` is lazy, so yes it can be constant time because it doesn't really do much work.  it returns something which when consumed as a seq, first fetches items from the first arg, then from the second when the first is exhausted.

Answer (score 15):

One way to get the union of two lists is to use `union`

```
Clojure> (into #{} (clojure.set/union '(1,2,3) '(3,4,5)))
#{1 2 3 4 5}
```

or if you want to get a list

```
(into '() (into #{} (clojure.set/union '(1,2,3) '(3,4,5))))
(5 4 3 2 1)
```

Comment: (-> #{} (into [1 2 3]) (into [3 4 5]) seq)

Comment: You aren't really achieving anything with `union` operating on list arguments. All it does is `(reduce conj '(1,2,3) '(3,4,5))`. `clojure.set` functions are designed to work with set arguments.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't mind duplicates, you can try [concat](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/concat) :

```
(concat '(1 2 3 ) '(4 5 6 1) '(2 3)) 
;;==> (1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is [flatten](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flatten):

```
(def colls '((1 2 3) (2 3 4)))
(flatten colls) ;; => (1 2 3 2 3 4)
(distinct (flatten colls)) ;; => (1 2 3 4)
```

One thing to be aware of is that it will flatten deeply nested collections:

```
(flatten [[1 2 [3 4 5]] [1 [2 [3 4]]]]) ;; => (1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4)
```

But works well for maps:

```
(flatten [[{} {} {}] [{} {} {}]]) ;; => ({} {} {} {} {} {})
```